# Как в SQL базе сделать так чтобы несколько столбцов могли иметь только разные значение в одной строке?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть  PostgreSQL  База нужно , чтобы  столбец  `col_1` и `col_2` могли иметь только разные значение, то есть
нужно предотвратить тот сценарий где делается insert с равными друг другу значениями  `col_1` и `col_2`.

Есть ли решение этой задачи на уровне СУБД  например вовремя создания таблицы и как лучше всего добиться этого условия ?

Comment: Ну есть такая штука как CHECK constraint. Оно умеет. А если написано правильно, оно даже два NULL не разрешит.

Comment: @Akina  А как использовать их в  контексте  вопроса ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ... ( -- создание таблицы
... ,              -- всякие прочие поля
col1 ... ,         -- поле col1
... ,              -- ещё всякие прочие поля
col2 ... ,         -- и теперь поле соl2
... ,              -- и снова всякие прочие поля и иные конструкции
           -- ну и добрались до проверки нужного условия
CONSTRAINT col1_neq_col2 CHECK (col1 != col2),
           -- теперь в таблице никаким штатным способом не может появиться запись, 
           -- значения полей которой не выполняют этого условия
... ,
);
```

Ну а если таблица уже имеется, то вносим в неё изменения b добавляем показанное ограничение соотв. ALTER TABLE. Предварительно проверив, что все существующие записи не нарушают его. А если такие записи есть - предварительно исправляем либо удаляем их.